# A questionable rejected edit

Tags: discussion

Now I'm not one to quibble over minor matters (I'm quite a *laissez faire* type of chap), but I recently made an edit to a [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14782/im-looking-for-a-way-to-serially-communicate-with-a-multi-mesh-arduino-slave-net), which I was surprised to see rejected, especially when I saw the alternative accepted edit.

The edit that I proposed was the following:

> [image: Proposed edit]

I saw that it was rejected by the community for reasons of a subsequent edit,

> [image: Community rejection]

To which I thought "Fair enough, I must have missed something, my edit was not sufficient", and was going to leave it at that. However, curiosity got the better of me, and I decided to have a look at the replacement edit.

Imagine my surprise when the edit was merely to substitute a period for a comma, making it even more grammatically incorrect, whilst ignoring the obvious typos.

> [image: Actual edit]

I understand that the OP has the overall *say so* when it comes to edits, but also there is the point of once you have posted something to SE, it also becomes a bit of a community effort to keep everything "spick and span".

Now I know that I am a bit of a stickler for grammar and capitalisation, and that may put people's backs up a bit, but am I missing something?

Admittedly, I did miss the `spiting` (in the last paragraph) which should probably be `splitting` but I don't think that was the real reason for rejection.

Hopefully this doesn't sound like a whinge, I would just like to know what the outcome in such circumstances should be.

Should the post be left as it stands, or should I attempt to retry the edits?

Comment: I would categorically reject this edit - it is far, far too trivial a change to justify bumping a question back to the top of a page, which an edit does.  If you want to contribute to the site, do something meaningful, don't just "or" a few character codes with the caps bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an edit a little while back (quite an extensive one, like yours) but while I was doing it the OP made a minor change. Since the OP can edit immediately, my edit was rejected. I think I tried again (laboriously retyping the corrections) and while I did that, the OP made *another* change! Pffft!

I left it for a while, I can't remember if I ended up changing it.

I suspect this is not at all an attack on your editing (which is usually very good as I recall) but just an unfortunate time-related thing (like, a race condition).

I would advise you to re-attempt your edit.